# Puppeteer wrong result with evaluate() & exposeFunction()

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, evaluate

I ran the following and it appears to gather a large number of links, however on actual inspection of the site with `collectLinks1` I get all valid links, but with `collectLinks2` I got 59 iterations of `http://pieroxy.net/blog/2014/11/18/[`

I'm new to Puppeteer and I can't find out why with `collectLinks2` I don't get the links.

```
const { parse, resolve } = require('url');
const trim = require('lodash/trim');
const startsWith = require('lodash/startsWith');
const includes = require('lodash/includes');


// https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
// https://github.com/gwuhaolin/chrome-finder
const findChrome = require('chrome-finder'); 


function resolveUrl(url, baseUrl) {
  url = trim(url);
  if (!url) return null;
  if (startsWith(url, '#')) return null;
  const { protocol } = parse(url);
  if (includes(['http:', 'https:'], protocol)) {
    return url.split('#')[0];
  } if (!protocol) {
    return resolve(baseUrl, url).split('#')[0];
  }
  return null;
}

async function collectLinks1(htmlPage) {
  const baseUrl = htmlPage.url();
  const links = [];
  const assetUrls = await htmlPage.$$eval('a[href]', assetLinks => assetLinks.map(link => link.href));

  assetUrls.forEach(link => {
    const _link = resolveUrl(link, baseUrl);
    if (_link) links.push(_link);
  });

  return links;
}

async function collectLinks2(htmlPage) {
  const baseUrl = htmlPage.url();
  const links = [];

  await htmlPage.exposeFunction('pushToLinks', link => {
    const _link = resolveUrl(link, baseUrl);
    if (_link) links.push(_link);
  });

  await htmlPage.evaluate(() => {
    function findLinks(document) {
      document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')
        .forEach(link => {
          window.pushToLinks(link.href);
        });
    }
    findLinks(window.document);
  });

  return links;
}

const crawl = async url => {
  try {
    console.log(`Crawling ${url}`);

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      executablePath: findChrome(),
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url);

    // OK
    const links1 = await collectLinks1(page);
    links1.forEach(link => { console.log(link); });

    // KO
    const links2 = await collectLinks2(page);
    links2.forEach(link => { console.log(link); });

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

crawl('http://pieroxy.net/blog/2014/11/18/user_agent_detection_in_java.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the function defined via `page.exposeFunction` as it returns a Promise. As you are only calling the function but not awaiting its result, your `page.evaluate` call will resolve before your script finished executing.

**Solution**

Instead of the `forEach`, you should use a loop to iterate over all the items and communicate them to the page one after another.

```js
async function collectLinks2(htmlPage) {
  // ...

  await htmlPage.evaluate(async () => {
    async function findLinks(document) {
      for (const link of document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')) {
        await window.pushToLinks(link.href);
      }
    }
    await findLinks(window.document);
  });
  return links;
}
```

Comment: `await window.pushToLinks(link.href);` Parsing error: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: @LeMoussel I was missing an `async` in the code. Can you try again?

Comment: No more errors with `async`. However, we still have `http://pieroxy.net/blog/2014/11/18/[` as a result.